# Replacement Forks for Giant Roam 2 2012

Tags: fork, suspension

I would like to find an as similar as possible replacement fork for my 2012 Giant Roam 2. (They have rusted over time).

The full spec of the bike is here: http://www.giant-bicycles.com/en-gb/bikes/model/roam.2/9330/49862/

According to that site, the forks I am looking are the SR Suntour NEX 4610 Lock-out.

However, I cannot seem to get them online anywhere.

Any ideas of what types of forks I can get for this? On a budget!!

Answer (score 1):

Many OEM forks are not for sale directly to the public. This one very well may fall into that category. That said, there is no need to replace it with the exact same fork.

You just need to make sure to replace it with something that will fit. IE, the steerer tube is the correct diameter (probably 1 1/8", but you should verify before purchasing), that it is sized to accept 700c wheels & that it is made to accept disc brakes. 
Something like on of these may fit the bill:

[RockShox-Paragon-Turnkey-Aluminum-Steerer](http://smile.amazon.com/RockShox-Paragon-Turnkey-Aluminum-Steerer/dp/B00JZIRNPI/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1438266539&sr=8-5&keywords=700c%20suspension%20fork)

[SR-Suntour-NRX-Suspension-Threadless](http://smile.amazon.com/SR-Suntour-NRX-Suspension-Threadless/dp/B00H65082W/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1438266539&sr=8-2&keywords=700c%20suspension%20fork)

[sr-suntour-nrx-eld-700c-suspension-fork-electric-lockout-black](http://www.bikewagon.com/part/forks/suspension-forks/sr-suntour-nrx-eld-700c-suspension-fork-1-1-8-63mm-electric-lockout-black)

[rockshox-paragon-gold-65mm-700c](http://www.bikewagon.com/part/forks/suspension-forks/rockshox-paragon-gold-65mm-700c-suspension-fork-disc-brake-black)

Not to recommend any one over the other mind you.

For other options, I would just start googling "700c Threadless suspension fork".

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a easy to confirm it is tread less?

Comment: Take look here: http://www.sheldonbrown.com/headsets.html
You can tell pretty easily by looking at your steerer / stem.